# Loop Cuts - How to Stop Bending Outwards?

Tags: modeling, mesh, edges, loop

I'm an amateur games developer looking to make my first set of modular buildings for a new game in Unreal.

In this screenshot I'm looking to add some detail to the roof overhang by extruding some faces outward. The only thing is that the loop cuts I've added veer out away from the origin once they hit the inner edge, is there any way that I could cut them completely straight? It would be a massive help!

Thanks guys!

[image: highlighted loop cuts]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After creating the loop cuts, do these two steps.

First, set the pivot point to individual origins:
[image]

Then, do `S + X + 0` scale down the selected loop cuts on the x axis to zero, removing the outward bend on the edges:

[image: nobend]

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! This is exactly what I need :) much appreciated!